# AWS InvalidParameterValueException

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried this command.

```
$ aws support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result \
 --check-id eW7HH0l7J9 \
 --query 'result.sort_by(flaggedResources[?status!="ok"],&metadata[2])[?starts_with(metadata[2],`On-Demand`)].metadata' \
 --output table \
 --region us-east-1
```

And i got this error.

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the DescribeTrustedAdvisorCheckResult operation: Unknown ID: eW7HH0l7J9
```

Why is this error happening?
And how can I solve this error?

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check id you mentioned is not supported anymore. See [AWS Premium Support doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/ta-iam/#table2) for a list of supported check ids